# Handling Ratios/Divisions in C#

Tags: c#

Hello guys I am trying to divide 4 by 3 using c#.

I have tried the following so far and in each case the answer is 1

```
float a = 4/3;// returns a = 1
```

I have tried this with Decimal and still the result is the same. I am not a C programmer is there any way I can get a engineering result like `1.333`

Comment: You're dividing ints. Add `.0` to each number and you'll get what you want.

Comment: case 1 does not return 1

Comment: case 2 would only return 1, because 4/3 is int/int.

Comment: wow, ghost edit just removed the first case.

Comment: @Servy Must be a case of programmers gone wild :)

Comment: @FloodGravemind What?  Just do some research.  This is a *very* common problem with lots of information on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 gives me 1.333. Case 2 is actually integer division, because `4` and `3` are integers, defined in line.

`float a = 4f / 3;` will work as the RHS is then evaluated to floating point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'f' suffix to tell the compiler the literal is a float

```
float a = 4f / 3f;
```

Otherwise it will assume an integral and you will get an integral result.

Comment: Not it won't, it's specifically declared as a float. If he'd use `var`, then he should use the suffix. Edit: Oh ofcourse, nevermind. My mind was elsewhere.

Comment: it doesn't matter that a is declared as a float. 4 and 3 are literals. The compiler will assume they are integrals. 4/3 will produce 1 and a will be set to 1.0

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, No, having `a` declared as `float` wouldn't have any effect so `float a = 4 / 3` would return `1`

Comment: @WeylandYutani In the context of the original question this is a poor answer; in the context of the edited question it's not bad.  That's because this answer entirely ignored the first case, instead only discussing the second.

Comment: The original question was wrong. The first case was incorrect as I pointed out in the comments. So I ignored it.

Answer (score 2):

.NET have 3 types of division. From [`7.7.2 Division operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- Integer division
- Floating-point division
- Decimal division

With `float a = 4 / 3;` actually you are doing *integer division* and assign it in a float variable. As written in documentation;

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands.

If you want to do floating-point division, you can do one of these;

```
float a = 4f / 3f;
float a = 4 / 3f;
float a = 4f / 3;
```

Comment: Note that decimals are also floating points; it's the difference between base 10 and base 2 floating types.

Comment: @Servy Yes of course. I just wanted to point documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As both numbers are integers you are using the integer division

try with one or both float numbers

```
float a = 4 / 3f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the values `a` and `b` with `4.0` and `3.0` respectively

Comment: When they are stored in `float` variables they are converted to floats.  There is no need to do this.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary.  The example works in my environment as written.

Comment: Does not make sense. The 4 has already been converted to float upon assignment.